# Networkx: bipartites networks directed from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

From the dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp':[13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000113],
           'name_emp':['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin'],
       'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo']})
```

Drawing a network with the following code:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'id_emp', 'name_dep', ['name_emp'], 
create_using=nx.DiGraph())
deputado = "Ronaldo"

lista_subset_graph = list(df[df["name_dep"] == deputado]["id_emp"]) + [deputado]
H = G.subgraph(lista_subset_graph)
nx.draw(H, style = "solid", with_labels = True)
plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 7.5))
plt.show()
```

My current output(disregard the labels):

[image]

What do I need to do:

1 - Instead of a single edge directed with arrows on both edges, I need two edges, one as input and one as output of each node;

2 - I want to represent as a bipartite network, differentiating by the format the types of nodes (In the image the Luciano Ducci node corresponds to one column of the dataframe and the numbers to another, as I did in the dataframe example);

Comment: This seems quite broad and unclear. What is wrong with your code? What is it doing different to what you expect? Perhaps start from these points

Comment: please elaborate why the `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` is not sufficient

Comment: @yatu and Zachi Is it more understandable?